# Find minimum number of Bridges required to connect all the islands in a 2D binary matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, brute-force, heuristics

It's a variation of the famous problem of **Number of Islands**. I want to know the algorithm thinking approach(hint). If I want to connect all the islands given that island can be connected in all 8 directions **not in only 4 directions**. Then how should I approach this problem?

#### Example

Given

```
[[1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1]]
```

the expected output is `2`:

```
[[1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 2 0 2 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1]]
```

[as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kzuN.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried finding the shortest route between every area but I found this solution incorrect while cross-checking. And after that, I couldn't think of anything else.

Comment: I would use a search-tree algorithm. You need to have an heuristic for what is considered a good "move" (e.g. it reduces the number of islands). So, I'd say you first need some code to detect an islands and count the number of islands. It could be cool to parametrize such function(s) with the structure connection matrix (i.e. `[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]` in your case).

Comment: @norok2 I have adjusted the size of the image. Counting the number of islands,s not a problem. If required I can add code for detecting islands. But can you explain how the search-tree algorithm will be able to solve this problem. I didn't understand how it can solve the above problem. Can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: You try putting bridges and see if/by how much it improves the situation.